# Django Template double entry table

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have these models set up:

```
class Bar:
    name = models.CharField()
    foos = models.ManyToManyField(
        through='FooBar'
        through_fields=('bar','foo')
    )
class Foo:
    name = models.CharField()

class FooBar:
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar)
    value = models.DecimalField()
```

I'm trying to make a double entry table to show for each Bar, the value of its Foos, and n/a if the Bar doesn't have a value for this Foo.

This is what I want it to look like:

```
      [Foo1]  [Foo2]  [Foo3]
[Bar1]  4       n/a     n/a
[Bar2]  3       n/a      9
[Bar3] n/a       1      n/a
```

And this is the code I have:

```
<tr>
{%for foo in foo_list%}
    <th>{{foo.name}}</th>
{%endfor%}
</tr>
{%for bar in bar_list%}
    <th>{{bar.name}}</th>
    {%for foo in foo_list%}
        {%for foobar in bar.foobar_set.all%}
            {%if foobar.foo == foo%}
                <td>{{foobar.value}}</td>
            {%endif%}
        {%endfor%}
    {%endfor%}
</tr>
{%endfor%}
```

I can't figure out how to check if the foobar correspond to the foo.

I could do it with a `for i in range(0,foo_list.count())` and mess with the `i`, but I can't do this in Django Template Langage.

Comment: it will be better to create your data in your view. Create an header, with all your Foo, and a row list, with all your data about Bar / Foo relation. Logic is better in view or model. Not in template.

Comment: It's basically what I did. Only I put it in a tag instead of view

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I created a custom template tag to handle the logic.

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_bar_foos_values(bar, foo_list):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    output = []
    foobar_set = bar.foobar_set
    while(i < foo_set.count()):
        foo = foo_set.all()[i]
        if(j < foobar_set.count() and foobar_set.all()[j].foo == foo):
            output.append(foobar_set.all()[j].value)
            i = i+1
            j = j+1
        else:
            output.append("n/a")
            i = i+1
    return output
```

And in my template:

```
{%for bar in bar_list%}
    <tr>
        <th>{{bar.name}}</th>
        {%get_bar_foos_values bar foo_set as foobars%}
        {%for foobar in foobars%}
            <td>{{foobar}}</td>
        {%endfor%}
    </tr>
{%endfor%}
```

It may not be the best way to do it but it works for me. The only thing I did is move the algorithm from the template to a tag that I can write in real Python so with much more flexibility.